# Python selenium webdriver not working

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am running Python 2.7 under Ubuntu 14.04 environment. Usually my selenium works great and I used to code with that. My PC have never been touched for 4 months and I come back to code and find this error. Not sure what should I do.

The code is extremely simple:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver1.get("https://www.google.com")
```

And it brought up this error:

```
*File "/home/luke/python/gmail registry", line 11, in <module>
  driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 103, in __init__
  self.binary, timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
  self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
  self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 106, in _wait_until_connectable
  % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmp_W4qvw If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.*
```

I also tried use:

```
    driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver1.get("https://www.google.com")
```

And it turned out to be:

```
*File "/home/luke/python/gmail registry", line 11, in <module>
  driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
  desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 91, in __init__
  self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in start_session
  'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 231, in execute
  response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
  return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 426, in _request
  resp = self._conn.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1089, in getresponse
  response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 444, in begin
  version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 408, in _read_status
  raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''*
```

Thanks a lot! This really confused me.

My selenium is 2.53.1

Comment: have you tried uninstall/re-install selenium?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I tried : `sudo apt-get remove python-selenium`. And reinstalled again with `sudo apt-get install python-selenium`. Still same problem, I doubt that there probably something wrong with the chrome driver, I also tried to reinstall, but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to specify the path to your webdriver's exe like this :

```
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome('{path to your driver parent folder}/chromedriver.exe')
```